# How to output URL of Azure Logic Apps with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-logic-apps

I would like fetch url of logicapps, but getting errors.

How to modify Terraform code so that output works?
I'm not how to reference to Logic App instance and what is correct way to get url.

logicapp-main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "workflow-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "example" {
  name                = "workflow1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request" "example" {
  name         = "some-http-trigger"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.example.id#

  schema = <<SCHEMA
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Message": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
SCHEMA

}

output "logic_app_get_url" {
     value = some-http-trigger.logic_app_get_url
     description = "fetch url"
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on logicapp-main.tf line 91, in output "logic_app_get_url":
│   91:   value = some-http-trigger.logic_app_get_url
│
│ A managed resource "some-http-trigger" "logic_app_get_url" has not been declared in the root module.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do modify the output block in the above shared terraform code to fetch the callback url of the logic app.

```
output "url" {
    value = azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request.example.callback_url
}
```

**Here is the modified Terraform Code:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "workflow-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "example" {
  name                = "workflow1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request" "example" {
  name         = "some-http-trigger"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.example.id

  schema = <<SCHEMA
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "hello": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
SCHEMA

}
output "url" {
    value = azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request.example.callback_url
}
```

Here is the sample output for reference :

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly with regular main.tf. However when I copied and pasted it to main.tf of module I get error. What could be issue.

Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ..\modules\logicapp\main.tf line 33, in output "url":
│   33:     value = azurerm_logic_app_trigger_http_request.example.callback_url
│
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "callback_url".

Comment: @Kenny_I - you have to keep this output block inside the main.tf file under the module folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a callback url for a trigger in Logic App Standard then please see below.

Microsoft changed the way workflows are deployed under Logic App Standard.  The documentation is pretty poor so sharing this to help others struggling to find the magic combo.

The result requires a POST to the API so I used Terraform AZ API resource action to send the same using Terraform.

```
data "azapi_resource_action" "callback_url_data" {
  type = "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostruntime/webhooks/api/workflows/triggers@2022-03-01"
  action = "listCallbackUrl"
  resource_id = "/subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/<logicapp_resourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<logicapp_name>/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/<workflow_name>/triggers/<trigger_name>"
  response_export_values = ["*"]
}

output "callback_url" {
    value = jsondecode(data.azapi_resource_action.callback_url_data.output).value
}
```

References

[Azure API / App Service / Workflow Triggers - List Callback Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/workflow-triggers/list-callback-url?tabs=HTTP)

[Terraform AZ API Resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Azure/azapi/latest/docs/data-sources/azapi_resource_action)

[AZ API reference guide link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/hostruntime/webhooks/api/workflows/triggers?view=azurermps-6.0.0&pivots=deployment-language-terraform)

Comment: Thanks! I did some changes since my workflow is a consumption one, but it worked like a charm!

data "azapi_resource_action" "callback_url_data" {
  type        = "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers@2016-06-01"
  action      = "listCallbackUrl"
  resource_id = "/subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/${var.logicAppsNamePrefix}${var.environment}/triggers/${var.logicAppsTriggerName}"
  response_export_values = ["*"]
}

BTW mine was an existing workflow.